# I want this example on Microsoft, but there is no download link

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdn

The example listed here is perfect, but the download link is not on the page. Does anyone know of a template that is similar or where the download is? Thanks in advance:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997766.aspx#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a design example meant to show how those controls are used - that is, they are just images, and there is nothing more to download.  The apps themselves most likely don't exist.

But there is a large number of working app samples here, and you may find what you're looking for:  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples